# Oidc not available

Tags: quarkus

When my oidc is not available, I have this error 500 return on my endpoint generated by Quarkus :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Internal Server Error - Error handling c1d5a584-89d8-49ba-9df0-822ecb9b47da-3, io.quarkus.oidc.OIDCException:
        OIDC server is not available at the 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test' URL. Please make sure it is
        correct. Note it has to end with a realm value if you work with Keycloak, for example:
        'https://localhost:8180/auth/realms/quarkus'</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>...
```

Is it possible to customize this with a chosen error code and no content ?

I have tried with *ExceptionMapper* without success

Comment: Why do you want to customize that kind of error?, do you want to return a 503 or something ?

Comment: Yes this is what i want

Answer (score 0):

The exception mapper would be what you want, but you may need to use the JAX-RS way of implementing the mapper ([docs](https://quarkus.io/specs/jaxrs/2.1/index.html#exceptionmapper)). This lets you set an `@Priority` on the mapper implementation so that it triggers earlier than a default defined mapper which is likely what's happening with your request.